# Insert/remove UI based on radioButtons() value

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

It's been a while since I played around with Shiny, and I want to insert a UI and remove the UI whenever I toggle between two values of `radioButtons()`. Ideally, I want the Z `selectInput()` to appear whenever the user selects `TRUE` from the radio button; I'd also want it to disappear whenever the user selects `FALSE` from the radio button. Below I have some very sad code that makes the Z input appear but not disappear.

Any advice of how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Radio buttons
      radioButtons("partial_val","Partial",choices = c("TRUE","FALSE"), selected = "FALSE")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$partial_val==TRUE, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#partial_val",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = selectInput('z_var', 'Z', choices = '')
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$partial_val==FALSE, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "#z_var)"
    )
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you looked into `conditionalPanel`?

Comment: That might work. Know of the function but haven't played with it yet. Will do so and see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, an option is also switching to `conditionalPanel`:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Radio buttons
      radioButtons("partial_val","Partial",choices = c("TRUE","FALSE"), selected = "FALSE"),
      
      # Conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = 'input.partial_val == "TRUE"',
        selectInput('z_var', 'Z', choices = '')
      )
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )
    
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }
    
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an ID to remove it as shown below.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$partial_val, {
    if (input$partial_val==TRUE) {
      insertUI(
        selector = "#partial_val",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = tags$div(
          selectInput('z_var', 'Z', choices = ''),
          id = "myselect"
        )
      )
    } else if (input$partial_val==FALSE) {
      removeUI(
        selector = "#myselect"
      )
    }
    
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$partial_val==FALSE, {
  #   removeUI(
  #     selector = "#z_var)"
  #   )
  # })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )
    
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }
    
  })
}
```